# Laravel Route model binding with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am wondering if it is possible to return a relationship with laravels Route model binding ?

Say is a have a user model with a relationship 'friends' to other users, and I want to return both the user info and the relationship from a route or controller.

eg for the route `domain.tld/user/123`

```
Route::model('user', 'User');

Route::get('/user/{user}', function(User $user) {

    return Response::json($user);

});
```

this will return me the user info fine but I also want the relationships, is there any easy/proper way to do this ?

I know I can do this

```
Route::get('/user/{user}', function((User $user) {

    return Response::json(User::find($user['id'])->with('friends')->get());

});
```

or

```
Route::get('/user/{id}', function(($id) {

   return Response::json(User::find($id)->with('friends')->get());

});
```

but I suspect there may be a better way.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can populate the `$with` property in the User model. Like so;

```
protected $with = ['friends'];
```

This will autoload the relationship data for you automatically.

**Please Note:** This will do it for every user model query.

If you dont want friends to be loaded all the time, then you can bind it to the parameter within your route, like so;

```
Route::bind('user_id', function($id) {
    return User::with('friends')->findOrFail($id);
});

Route::get('/user/{user_id}', 'BlogController@viewPost');
```

Comment: **THANKS MAN**  `protected $with = ['friends'];` Saved my life (:

Answer (score 66):

You don’t want to eager-load relationships on *every* query like [Matt Burrow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2882596/matt-burrow) suggests, just to have it available in one context. This is inefficient.

Instead, in your controller action, you can load relationships “on demand” when you need them. So if you use route–model binding to provide a `User` instance to your controller action, but you also want the `friends` relationship, you can do this:

```php
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        $user->load('friends');

        return view('user.show', compact('user'));
    }
}
```

Edit: you can also conditionally load relations using `loadMissing`. This will only load the relation if it isn’t already loaded on the model:

```php
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        // If friends relation has already been loaded, will be a no-op
        $user->loadMissing('friends');

        return view('user.show', compact('user'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. You can also use `load` a little like `with`, for instance as part of a more complex query like: `return $module->load(['questions', 'questions.results' => function($q) use($user){ return $q->where('user_id', $user->id); }]);`

Comment: @Djave `load()` is for loading relationships _after_ a query’s been performed, `with()` is for including relationships as part of a query.

Comment: According to question, surely protected $with is worth the answer, but in overall according to app performance, this is what we should follow. Just load explicitly when you need it.

Answer (score 7):

Martin Bean's response is probably not the way you want to tackle this, only because it introduces an n+1 to your Controller:

1) It must load the `User` via Route Model Binding, then....

2) It now loads the relationship for `friends`

He is correct, however, that you probably don't want to load the relationship every time.

This is why Matt Burrow's solution is probably better (he's binding a different value: instead of `{user}`, you could use something like `{user_with_friends}` and bind that separately from `{user}`...

Personally, I think if you need to load `friends` for only that route, I'd simply just pass $userId (without binding), and just begin the controller method with:

`$user = User::with('friends')->findOrFail($userId);`

You can either let Laravel handle the ModelNotFoundException automatically (like it does with Route Model Binding), or wrap it in a try/catch

Comment: _Martin Bean's response is probably not the way you want to tackle this, only because it introduces an n+1 to your Controller_. No, it doesn’t.

Comment: How exactly would an N+1 problem be introduced when we're talking about route model binding - ie: a single model is being returned. Surely `$user->load('friends')` is just going to load the related friends once because there's only one `$user`.