# Cannot load eloquent model's relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to *load* a relationship for a model that is retrieved using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding) via the `load()` method, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
public function update(UpdateOrganisationFormRequest $request, Organisation $organisation)
{
    $organisation->load('contacts');

    dd(
        $organisation->contacts, // returns empty collection
        Organisation::first()->contacts // returns values I generated via factory
    );
}
```

These answers suggest that this is the correct way to do this:

[Eager loading with route model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406089/eager-loading-with-route-model-binding)

[Laravel Route model binding with relaionship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888736/laravel-route-model-binding-with-relaionship)

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-model-binding-with-eager-loading

Here are my relationship definitions:

```
class Organisation extends Model
{
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrganisationContact::class);
    }
}

class OrganisationContact extends Model
{
    public function organisation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Organisation::class);
    }
}
```

I have considered *Customizing The Resolution Logic* but seems a little overkill as I only need some relationships loaded for this update process.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

**Update**

Thanks to the comments I realised that the route model binding is not returning anything. For some further context... I am running a test where I generate an `Organisation` model, then hitting the update route for this resource, the code looks like this:

**Test class:**

```
/** @test */
public function existing_organisation_can_be_updated()
{
    // Arrange
    $organisation = factory(Organisation::class)->create();

    factory(OrganisationContact::class)->create([
        'organisation_id' => $organisation->id,
    ]);

    /*
        note:
        dd( route('admin.organisation.update', $organisation->id) )
        produces: "http://mydevurl.dev/admin/organisation/1"
    */

    // Act
    $response = $this->put(route('admin.organisation.update', $organisation->id), [
        'name' => 'New name',
    ]);

    // ... assertions and other stuff
}
```

**Resource controller**

```
public function update(UpdateOrganisationFormRequest $request, Organisation $organisation)
{
    // this return null ???
    dd(
        $organisation->id    
    );

    // update logic ...
}
```

**Update 2 - schema**

_create_organisations_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateOrganisationsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('organisations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            // some other fields
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('organisations');
    }
}
```

_create_organisation_contacts

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateOrganisationContacts extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('organisation_contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            // some other fields
            $table->timestamps();

            // the relationship
            $table->foreign('organisation_id')->references('id')->on('organisations')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('organisation_contacts');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$organisation` from parameter and `Organisation::first()` are the same?

Comment: Show your schema, please. You may also want to check if that particular organization has any contacts.

Comment: try this `Organisation::find($organisation->id)->contacts` and see if there are some !!

Comment: @Laerte Yes, however the route model binding doesn't seem to work, see the update to the question I made

Comment: @aynber I added the schema, see update 2 on the question. The organisation has contacts as I'm generating them with a factory in a test. The issue seems to be with the route model binding not working (clearly I'm doing something wrong?)

Comment: @Maraboc see the updates to my question. `$organisation->id` returns null, so it seems the model is not being retrieved properly, any ideas why?

Comment: What happens if you do `dd($organisation);` ?

Comment: @aynber `dd($organisation)` returns an empty `Organisation` object... I just remembered this project I am working on went through an upgrade so it may be something to do with that! Currently 5.5 and was previously 5.3, time to check the docs upgrade guide!

Comment: My `app\Http\Kernel.php` has `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,` in the `web` `$middlewaresGroup` and `'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,` in `$routeMiddleware` - so perhaps this isn't an issue?

Comment: When I run the code through the browser `dd($organisation)` in the update method returns the `Organisation` model with its current info in the DB. Why is this not working for the test?

Comment: Ahhh it's because I had the `WithoutMiddleware` trait being used which pulled out the binding which is managed via the middleware

Comment: You ffigureitout your self ;) nice !

Comment: @Maraboc Thanks! And thanks a lot for your comments you definitely helped me get to the solution. Hopefully, this benefitted you too - lesson learnt: do not use `WithoutMiddleware` in tests with your eyes closed!

Comment: agree, but not all the time because there are some cases where you have to disable midlewares for test for example disable CSRF token midleware ... !!

Comment: Sure, it's not an absolute truth but the cause for why the route model binding wasn't working. How to get both working would be interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Organisation` model is not retrieved via *route model bindings* because the `WithoutMiddleware` trait is being used in the test!

As of Laravel 5.3 route model binding is accomplished via Middleware:

> **Binding Substitution Middleware**
>
> Route model binding is now accomplished using middleware. All applications should add the `Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings` to your web middleware group in your  app/Http/Kernel.php file
>
> ...
>
> https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

By using the `WithoutMiddleware` trait you are stopping the route model binding from being triggered.

Remove the `WithoutMiddleware` for it to function as expected.

See further discussion here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15163